# How to call constructor from derived class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inventory

Let say I have a `Item` base class

```
public class Item
{
    var SomeVariable;
    var OtherVariable;
    
    public Item(some parameter)
    {

    }
}
```

and a derived class called Gun

```
public class Gun : Item
{
    var SomeVariable;
    public Gun(Some Parameter)
    {

    }

}
```

and the `Item` class Constructor is represent as actual item in `Inventory`. like when player picked up `GameObject` with `Item` class attach to it it will added to the `Inventory` using the Method `Add Item`

```
public bool AddItem(Item _item, int _amount)
{
    //add Item to Inventory object
}
```

as you can see the Method `Add Item` is using `Item` as parameter, so when a `Gun` `GameObject` pickup by player it won't added to `inventory` do I need to change how the system work or it can be fixed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the base constructor from your derived class in this way:

```
public class Gun : Item
{
    var SomeVariable;
    public Gun(Some Parameter) : base(Some Parameter)
    {
    }
}
```

But it's not clear what the actual issue is, since you don't need to initialize the passed `Item` in `AddItem`. Simply put it to your inventory instance. Assuming you have an instance of it there:

```
public bool AddItem(Item item, int amount)
{
    inventory.Add(item, amount); // just guessing
}
```

> So when a Gun GameObject pickup by player it won't added to inventory
> do I need to change how the system work or it can be fixed ?

I think i get your misunderstanding now. Since a `Gun` actualls IS an `Item`, you can call `AddItem` with a `Gun` instance. That's one of the advantages of inheritance.

```
AddItem(new Gun(Some Parameter), 1);
```